# I have multiple error in the following code. The errors listed below. Any Solutions?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have an error " This LinearLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless" in line no 21 and error "Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_centerHorizontal" in lines 29 and 30.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <fragment android:id="@+id/peta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_list_smk">
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: layout_centerHorizontal and layout_centerVertical those attributes are used inside RelativeLayout. Not with LinearLayout. Instead of those use  android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting layouts unnecessarily. Just remove the linear layout.

Also you are seeing that error
Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout:layout_centerHorizontal" 
Because it's not at an attribute that can be used inside a frame layout.

Just remove the linear layout tag and make spinner a direct child to the frame layout.